# clearing animation from Tic Tac Toe/Noughts & Crosses in Android

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to clear an animation (which is a set of three blinking buttons in a 'line') with pressing a button I assigned to this game that clears the board via the "clearGame" method shown below. However while upon playing the game winning it (have not set the buttons yet, will do later) it shows the 3-line-blinking correctly (let's say with buttons 1,4,7) and when I call up the "clearGame" method it resets the board. However, for some reason if I win the game a second time with another set of buttons (say example I win with buttons 3,6,9) it shows both set of buttons (say 3,6,9 & 1,4,7) blinking instead of just one set. Here's the activity for the main game:

```
package com.example.noughtsandcrosses;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoughtsAndCrossesXActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
    Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
    int[] squares = new int[10];
    Button newGame;
    Button exitGame;
    TextView WinGame;
    Animation WinningAnim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noughts_and_croses);    

        buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        buttons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);  
        newGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_game);
        newGame.setOnClickListener(this);
        WinGame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.win_game);
        exitGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_game);
        exitGame.setOnClickListener(this);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);    

            clearGame();
        }

        WinningAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.winning_animation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void clearGame(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
            buttons[i].setText("");
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
            squares[i] = 0;
        }
        WinGame.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.one:
            makeMove(1);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.two:
            makeMove(2);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.three:
            makeMove(3);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.four:
            makeMove(4);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.five:
            makeMove(5);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.six:
            makeMove(6);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.seven:
            makeMove(7);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.eight:
            makeMove(8);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.nine:
            makeMove(9);
            respond();
            break;
        case R.id.new_game:
            System.out.println("newgame");
            clearGame();
            break;
        case R.id.exit_game:
            System.out.println("exitgame");
            //exitGameToMenu(); 
            Intent a = new Intent (this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void CheckIfPlayerWon (int i) {
        i = 1;
        if (squares[1] == i && squares[2] == i && squares[3] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 1");
            buttons[1].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[2].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[3].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[4] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[6] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 2");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[5].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[6].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[7] == i && squares[8]== i && squares[9] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 3");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[8].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[9].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
        }
        else if (squares[1]== i && squares[4] == i && squares[7] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 4");
            buttons[1].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[2] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[8] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 5");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[3] == i && squares[6] == i && squares[9] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 6");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
        }
        else if (squares[1] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[9] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 7");
            buttons[1].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
        }
        else if (squares[3] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[7] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have won the game! 8");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].startAnimation(WinningAnim);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void CheckIfPlayerLost (int i) {
        i = 2;
        if (squares[1] == i && squares[2] == i && squares[3] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 1");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[4] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[6] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 2");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[7] == i && squares[8]== i && squares[9] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 3");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[1]== i && squares[4] == i && squares[7] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 4");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[2] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[8] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 5");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[3] == i && squares[6] == i && squares[9] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 6");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[1] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[9] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 7");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (squares[3] == i && squares[5] == i && squares[7] == i){
            WinGame.setText("You have lost the game! 8");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void makeMove(int i) {
        buttons[i].setText("X");
        buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
        squares[i] = 1;
        CheckIfPlayerWon(i);
    }


    public void respond() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (buttons[i].isEnabled()) {
                buttons[i].setText("O");
                buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
                squares[i] = 2;
                CheckIfPlayerLost(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? I have tried to enter a line (say "WinningAnim.clearAnimation()" to reset the animation in the clearGame Method but that causes the game to crash when I start but when I remove the line it is fine (except with the animation problem).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very comfortable with Android, but as far as I could tell from digging around the documentation (should always be your first stop when you have a problem), you are using the wrong object when you are calling clearAnimation(). As far as I can tell, class Animation (which is what WinningAnim is) does not even have a clearAnimation() method. I imagine that some sort of error should have tipped you off to this. Also the Animation you loaded from loadAnimation(context,id) is a static animation, so you will only want to mess with that in a static context.

You might want to try calling clearAnimation() on you buttons, because those are children classes of View which does have a method called clearAnimation() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation()).

Also, you should really rewrite large portions of your code, you should consolidate code into methods and/or simplify it.

for example:

- If you have a winner you have a loser, no need to check for both winning and losing
- Replace that horribly long chain of if statements with something more elegant (maybe a loop?)

As a rule of thumb, if it looks like you are doing the exact same thing multiple times with minor variation, you can usually replace it with much more elegant code.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks, though I need to get this done before monday and re-writing to streamline the methods for finding out the winner & loser is. Though for the clear animation method, how should I go aroudn implementing it?

Comment: you would insert it into your clear game method when you are looping through, just put this in : 'buttons[i].clearAnimation()'. try this.